In what sense are preadditive categories also enriched categories?
I'm confused about Wikipedia's definition of preadditive categories:

In mathematics, specifically in category theory, a preadditive category is another name for an Ab-category, i.e., a category that is enriched over the category of abelian groups, Ab. That is, an Ab-category $\mathcal C$ is a category such that every hom-set Hom$(A,B)$ in $\mathcal C$ has the structure of an abelian group, and composition of morphisms is bilinear, in the sense that composition of morphisms distributes over the group operation.

The implication is that an Ab-enriched category is just a category whose hom-sets are equipped with a certain compatible group structure. On its face, this makes no sense, because enriched categories are not categories (at least according to all the definitions I've found). They do, however, induce ordinary categories, as I asked about here. So I take it that there is some sense in which these two definitions of preadditive categories as equivalent. My question is, in what sense exactly?

Here is my current idea. Please let me know if this is correct, and also whether I'm missing any big ideas that would further clarify this.
A preadditive category is a pair $(\mathcal C, \bar{\mathcal C})$, where $\mathcal C$ is a category and $\bar{\mathcal C}$ is an Ab-enriched category, such that either of the following equivalent pairs of conditions holds.

$\mathcal C$-first version

Each hom-set in $\mathcal C$ is equipped with an operation + turning it into an abelian group. Moreover, $\circ$ distributes over +.
$\bar{\mathcal C}$ is the Ab-enriched category defined from $\mathcal C$ as follows. The objects of $\bar{\mathcal C}$ are the same as those of $\mathcal C$, and the hom-sets are the objects of Ab corresponding to the abelian groups of the hom-sets in $\mathcal C$. For each $\bar{\mathcal C}$ object $a$, the identity morphism is given by $\text{id}_a = \{0\} \ni 0 \mapsto 1_a \in \bar{\mathcal C}(a, a)$, where $1_a$ is the identity morphism in $\mathcal C(a, a)$. For any triple $\{a, b, c\}$ of $\bar{\mathcal C}$ objects, composition in $\mathcal C$ given by $\circ : \mathcal C(b, c) \times \mathcal C(a, b) \to \mathcal C(a, c)$ is $\mathbb Z$-bilinear when the hom-sets are considered as abelian groups, hence it induces a unique homomorphism $\circ_{abc} : \bar{\mathcal C}(b, c) \otimes \bar{\mathcal C}(a, b) \to \bar{\mathcal C}(a, c)$. We let $\circ_{abc}$ be the enriched composition morphism in Ab for $\bar{\mathcal C}$.


$\bar{\mathcal C}$-first version

$\bar{\mathcal C}$ is an Ab-enriched category.
$\mathcal C$ is isomorphic (or just equivalent?) to the category induced by $\bar{\mathcal C}$.



One would have to check, I think, that $(1)$ $\bar{\mathcal C}$ really is an Ab enriched category according to the first definition (it must satisfy certain commuting diagrams), and $(2)$ the abelian group structure inherited by hom-sets in $\mathcal C$ from $\bar{\mathcal C}$, according to the second definition, makes $\circ$ distribute over +.

That's essentially correct. I believe what people usually have in mind is something like this: One really thinks of an $\mathrm{Ab}$-enrichment (here) as additional data on the hom-sets of an ordinary category, because $\mathrm{Ab}$ is so concrete: An abelian group is just a set with structure, after all, and a morphism just a certain kind of function (of sets). In particular, you can go from the enriched category to the underlying category easily through the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Ab} \to \mathrm{Set}$.

Yeah, an $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched category "is" a preadditive category in the same sense that an abelian group "is" a set with the structure of an abelian group. To make "is" precise you can talk about equivalence of (2-)categories, but this is a bit unnecessary (and would depend on the foundations you are working in). The pair construction is also overkill.

I think I get the main idea, but I'm confused by the part where morphisms in $\mathcal C$ become morphisms out of $I$ in the enriched category. This makes the enriched version of the category feel different from the original category.

@WillG Here you should note that $I = \mathbb{Z}$, and for any abelian group $G$ you have a natural bijection of sets $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, G) \cong G$ (this is what it means for $\mathbb{Z}$ to be "free of rank 1", to stay categorial), so you recover the elements of $\overline{\mathcal{C}}(a, b)$ in the set-theoretic sense. From this vantage point, one should think of morphisms out of $I$ in a general enriched category as the best analogue to set-theoretic elements you have when the objects of the category you're enriching in need not be set-like at all.

This is a standard categorical sleight of hand: "is" means "there is a canonical isomorphism in some appropriate sense". Indeed, as you have noted, if $\mathcal{V}$ is a monoidal category, the functor $\mathcal{V}(I,-)\colon\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$ gives rise to the "underlying category" $2$-functor $U:\mathcal{V}-\mathbf{CAT}\rightarrow\mathbf{CAT}$ from the (large) $2$-category of $\mathcal{V}$-enriched categories to the (large) $2$-category of ordinary categories.
In case $\mathcal{V}=\mathbf{Ab}$ with its usual monoidal structure, the tensor unit is $I=\mathbb{Z}$ and the functor $\mathbf{Ab}(\mathbb{Z},-)\colon\mathbf{Ab}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$ is just the forgetful functor taking an abelian group to its underlying set. Thus, the underlying category $U\mathcal{C}$ of an $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched category $\mathcal{C}$ has the same objects and its Hom-sets are just the underlying Hom-sets of the Hom-objects of $\mathcal{C}$. Now, suppose $f\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ and $g\in\mathcal{C}(Y,Z)$. These are interpreted as morphisms $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ resp. $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}(Y,Z)$ in $\mathbf{Ab}$, given by $1\mapsto f$ resp. $1\mapsto g$. Then, the composite
$$\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}(Y,Z)\otimes\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\rightarrow\mathcal{C}(X,Z)$$
maps $1\mapsto\circ_{XYZ}(g\otimes f)$, hence the composition in $U\mathcal{C}$ is given by the composite
$$\mathcal{C}(Y,Z)\times\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\rightarrow\mathcal{C}(Y,Z)\otimes\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\rightarrow\mathcal{C}(X,Z).$$
From this description, it is immediate that if we "manually" remember the additive structure on each Hom-set, $U\mathcal{C}$ becomes a preadditive category in the sense of having an abelian group structure on each Hom-set s.t. composition becomes bilinear. Thus, you can consider $U$ as a $2$-functor from the (large) $2$-category of $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched categories to the (large) $2$-category of preadditive categories(*) and this is an isomorphism. In this sense, a preadditive category is the same thing as an $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched category.
(*) This statement has additional content, for we have to define what a functor between preadditive categories and a natural transformation between such functors are.

Thanks, this helps a lot. Is the abstract $2$-functor $U : \mathcal V$-$\mathbf{CAT} \to \mathbf{CAT}$ an isomorphism, or is this a special property when $\mathcal V = \mathbf{Ab}$?

@WillG No, it is typically not an isomorphism. It is also not an isomorphism for $\mathcal{V}=\mathbf{Ab}$. It becomes an isomorphism when you interpret it as a $2$-functor into the $2$-category of preadditive categories instead.
